# Toggle buttons without refreshing using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

The problem is that all the "into it" buttons on the page have the same id and all the "undo" have the same id thus clicking one offsets others. Also the buttons only toggle once. I'm very new to rails,CSS,ajax and I appreciate the help, thank you.
[image]

Micropost_Helper.rb

```
def toggle_like_button(micropost, user)
  if user.voted_for?(micropost)
    link_to "undo", like_micropost_path(micropost), :class => "btn btn-mini btn-primary", :id =>"unvote_form", :remote => true
  else
    link_to "Into it!", like_micropost_path(micropost), :class => "btn btn-mini btn-primary", :id =>"vote_form", :remote => true
  end
end
```

Micropost Controller

```
def like
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  if @micropost.user_id != @current_user
    if @current_user.voted_for?(@micropost)
      @current_user.unvote_for(@micropost)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.js
      end
    else
      @current_user.vote_for(@micropost)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
end
```

VIEW/microposts/like.js.erb  <-- with this i can only click the button's once, need help here as well

```
$("#vote_form").html("undo")
$("#unvote_form").html("Into it!")
```

Comment: so you're working with invalid html

Comment: not sure what you mean, is there no simple way to fix this issue?

Comment: an id should be unique in one page. Your main issue is that you work with unscoped js, you hit the whole dom every time.

Comment: Every element on a html page has to have a unique ID. I suggest prefixing the id of the post to your button

Comment: Thanks, your question becomes my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should append uniq id to each button like this:

```
def toggle_like_button(micropost, user)
  if user.voted_for?(micropost)
    link_to "undo", like_micropost_path(micropost), :class => "btn btn-mini btn-primary", :id =>"unvote_form_#{micropost.id}", :remote => true
  else
    link_to "Into it!", like_micropost_path(micropost), :class => "btn btn-mini btn-primary", :id =>"vote_form_#{micropost.id}", :remote => true
  end
end
```

and then you can reference one button in your like.js.erb:

```
$("#vote_form_<%=@micropost.id%>").html("undo")
$("#unvote_form_<%= @micropost.id%>").html("Into it!")
```

That way you will have valid html and your problem should be solved.

Comment: I dont think it can find these #vote_form_#{@micropost.id}. the button  does get a unique id now i checked the html --> id="unvote_form_361" an example of a button

Comment: Confirmed #{@micropost.id} is failing to return a number in the like.js.erb file

Comment: Proper syntax is that the ruby must be embedded: $("#vote_form_<%=@micropost.id%>").html("undo")
$("#unvote_form_<%=@micropost.id%>").html("Into it!")